# sbt file doesn't recognize the spark input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I try to execute Scala code in Spark. The example of the code and `build.sbt` file is possible to find [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-first-app.html).

I have one difference to this example. I use already the version `2.0.0` of Spark (I have already download this version local and defined path in .bashrc file). Now, I have modified also my `build.sbt` file and set the version to `2.0.0` 
After that I have the error message.

Case 1:
I just executed the code of `SparMeApp` like is given in the link. I got the error message, that I have to define `setMaster` function.

```
16/09/05 19:37:01 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

Case 2:
I define `setMaster` function with different arguments. I have got next error messages:

Input: `setMaster("spark://<username>:7077)` or `setMaster("local[2]")`
Error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

(this error means that my string is empty)

In other cases just error: `16/09/05 19:44:29 WARN`

```
StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master <...>
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
```

Additional I have only a little experience in Scala and in sbt. So probably my sbt is configutred false.... Can somebody, please, tell me the right way?

Comment: how you are running your application ? Using spark-submit or by running your main class ?

Comment: From the terminal. First `sbt` and later `run`. I have errors by the running of the second command

Comment: if you are running spark application locally there is no need to install spark in your local machine. Try to have the latest version of spark client library in your build.sbt file, try with sbt clean run. And don't forget to set appMaster like "local[*]" in while initialising spark context.

Comment: @Abhi, thank you for your help. I though, I did it alredy by the putting of the next line in `build.sbt` file: `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" `

Comment: Can you share the exception which you are getting while having latest spark in build.sbt and running with "sbt clean run" ? And also you need to pass single argument, else try with some hardcoded value.

Comment: `[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`
 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122699/discussion-between-abhi-and-guforu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your minimal build.sbt will look :

```
name := "SparkMe Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

organization := "pl.japila"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
```

And here is your SparkMeApp object :

```
object SparkMeApp{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("SparkMe Application")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val fileName = args(0)
    val lines = sc.textFile(fileName).cache

    val c = lines.count
    println(s"There are $c lines in $fileName")
  }
}
```

execute it like :

$ sbt "run [your file path]"

Answer (score 0):

@Abhi, thank you very much for your answer. In general it works. Anyway I have some error message after the correct execution of the code. 
I have created some test txt file with 4 lines

```
test file
test file
test file
test file
```

In the SparkMeApp I have changed the code line to:

```
val fileName = "/home/usr/test.txt"
```

After I execute the line `run SparkMeApp.scala` I got next output:

```
16/09/06 09:15:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at SparkMeApp.scala:11, took 0.348171 s
There are 4 lines in /home/usr/test.txt
16/09/06 09:15:34 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
16/09/06 09:15:34 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:66)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:64)
16/09/06 09:15:34 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://<myip>:4040
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Sep 6, 2016 9:15:34 AM
```

I can see the correct output of my code (second line), but after I have got the interrupt error. How I can fix it? Anyway, I do hope the code is worked currently.

Comment: you can try with sbt universal:packageBin and you will find your zip in target/universal. Unzip it wherever you want and go to bin directory there you will find xxx.sh run it with your argument, hope it will not show such exceptions.

Comment: @Abhi, ok - thank you. I will try to fix according your solution.